# Dual power with lm1117 5V

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator

I am working on RGB light strips. I have created the circuit that includes at Atmega 328P processor. See attached image.

I have question about applying dual power supply.

If using only 5V supply, I could feed the Atmega chip directly and also the led strip (addressable that uses 5V supply).

Using only 12V supply, it will feed different led strip (non addressable) that runs on 12V source. Also it will feed power to +5V regulator. At its output, it will feed 5V to the processor.

Now the question is... If connecting two power source ( to drive two different strips at the same time), as in the diagram, is it safe to run as in this circuit? I haven't tested with dual power yet.
Note:  +5V source is also connected to the output of regulator. [image: drawing]

Comment: If you have a regulator that generates 5V out of 12V, why do you need a separate 5V source?

Comment: LM1117 regulator generates the output of 800mA, which may not be enough to drive the LED strip (the one with +5V, Data, & GND), but just enough to operate the MCU.  I have a star project that I intend to use with this board. It takes about 9.2amps of current. That's why I would like to supply with +5V 10A of power.  Also for the right side, +12V 10A as well.

That's for the worst case scenario.

I've designed the circuit that would provide some flexibility to drive either one of the strips or both.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that your LEDs and 5V and on 12V both need around 10A of current. And you have two power supply with 5V and 12V. Thus just connect the Grounds and use the 12V supply for the 12V stripes and the 5V supply for the Arduino and the 5V stripes. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

No, because if the two voltage supplies have even a little bit of variance in the voltage each supplies then you could burn out one or both of them. If you add a ballast resistor to the external 5V input then the voltage difference would result in a dissipation of power in the resistor rather than either supply.

A 0.5ohm resistor with a 0.5V difference would consume 500mW, which a 1W or 2W resistor could handle (although using a 5W device would not in any way be a bad idea). At the same time, it would only have a 75mV drop if the MCU were to draw 150mA from the external supply if it was the only one connected, resulting in a voltage well above what the ATmega328P calls for.

You also want to reverse-bypass the LDO with a schottky diode in case someone shorts the 12V input to ground with the 5V supply connected so that the current doesn't flow through the LDO's internal parasitic diode, thereby burning it out.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvgfuT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I am thinking of the alternative... by adding the "power source" switch to the MCU circuit.

Note: The switch would be "ON-OFF-ON" switch  ("12V-OFF-5V")

[image: Alternative circuit]

Comment: What functionally are you expecting from this switch? Is it your intention to turn the 5V strip off? A better way of doing this, is to switch of the 5V power supply off and use a diode between the output of the LM1117 and the 5V LED strip input.